# error passing value from a ng-model to another ng-model using ng-change

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-change

For the first input of 'a.html', user can select from the drop down list or enter a value.

For the second input, the default value is set to be the same as first input. User can later change the value in the second input. The value from the second input will then pass to function setPath for b.js.

After I have input a value 'android' in the first input, the second input will then default to 'android' as well. I am getting console error after I have removed all values in the second input and trying to input a new value. 
It says " cannot create property name on string 'android'.

a.html

```
 // first input
<input type="text" ng-model="result.c" data-auto-select="true"
       ng-change="result.path = result.c; checkIfMatch()"
       ng-blur="checkIfMatch()" bs-options="c as c.name for c in cs" />

 // second input
<input type="text" ng-disabled="!result.c.id" ng-model="result.path.name"/>
```

a.js

```
  $scope.checkIfMatch = function(){
      if(!$scope.result.c || $scope.result.c && $scope.result.c.id){
         return;
      } else{  
         var c = $scope.result.c;
          for(var i = 0; i < $scope.cs.length; i++){
            if(c == $scope.cs[i].name){
              $scope.result.c = $scope.cs[i];
              return;
            }
          }
      }
  };
```

b.js

```
function setPath() {
   $modal.open({
       templateUrl: '/xxx/a.html',
       scope: scope,
       controller: 'aController',
       windowClass: 'aModal'
      }).result.then(function(result){
     // scope.result.path.name to be the same value as second input in a.html
         var anchorTag = '<a href="' + result.c.id +'">Launch '+  result.path.name + '</a>';
 }
```

if i change the code for ng-change of first input at a.html, the value doesn't show up for the second input after moving cursor out of the first input. Still new to twitter bootstrap bs-options.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="result.c" data-auto-select="true"
       ng-change="result.path = result.c.name; checkIfMatch()"
       ng-blur="checkIfMatch()" bs-options="c as c.name for c in cs" />
```

// second input

```
<input type="text" ng-disabled="!result.c.id" ng-model="result.path"/>
```

Comment: this doesn't really make sense.  your `ng-model` in the first input box of `type=text` is `result.c`, which would make `result.c` a string.  however, you are later referring to it like it's an object, and trying to use `result.c.id`, `result.c.name`, etc..  Because it's a string, it's also being copied as a string, meaning `result.path` is also a string, so `result.path.name` wouldn't work either.

Comment: perhaps your `ng-model` is supposed to be `result.c.name`?

Comment: What is the `bs-options` directive? Is it a third-party library? If so, maybe that directive is causing the problem and you should contact that  library`s customer support.

Comment: bs-options is twitter bootstrap library

Comment: I would like to set b.js  anchorTag value to be the same value as the second input at a.html (If the value of second input is later changed by the user, would like b.js anchorTag value to be the same as second input). If I change the ng-model to be result.c.name, the b.js anchorTag value is folowing the same value as the first input. Would like it to be the same as the second input.

Comment: you miss my point, I think.  If `result.c` is an object, then you set it as the `ng-model` on a **text box**, you are overwriting the object with a string, which will break the object when you try to use it later in other places.  Unless that `bs-options` directive does something tricky.....

Comment: is there other way that I can  set b.js  anchorTag value to be the same value as the second input at a.html (If the value of second input is later changed by the user, would like b.js anchorTag value to be the same as second input).

Comment: And what is other way that I can set second input value to be the same as first input value, and also allow the user to edit/modify the second input value ? Yeah you are right, result.c is an object, and I am not sure how to pass the  retrieve the 'name' value from first input selected object to the text box for second input.

Comment: I think I figured out a soliution. I will define another scope separately in one of the function for a.js, and pass the scope reference in the function to b.js.

Comment: Althouhg I am able to pass the second reference in the function at a.js to b,js, still having problem of the ng-model for the second input box. Because the user will be able to edit the value in the first input , which will possibly make the value in the first input to be invalid, and then the second input ng-model will not be able to retrieve the result.c.name value.